# Wildfly Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: wildfly

I have downloaded Wildfly 10 (final), and was trying to configure it, like adding a user or register a driver, but each time i try to execute any of the `bat` scripts such as `add-user.bat` or the `jboss-cli.bat` i keep getting `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`.
I know that Wildfly 10 supports only Java8, and im actually using Java8 ..

```
C:\programming\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Check your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable as suggested. `echo %JAVA_HOME%` should show you that.

Comment: It works for me. JAVA_HOME was not set.

Answer (score 4):

(Excuse me if my terminology is off -- I'm a unix developer)

Does Wildfly depend upon the JAVA_HOME environment variable to locate the JRE? Most applications do, rather than your execution path. If JAVA_HOME is pointing at a JRE version earlier than 8, you may not actually be running Wildfly with 8 (that's exactly what it sounds like).